# FASTQC overrepresented sequences after trimming

Tags: ngs, fastq, trimming

I have a set of RNA-seq samples from different experiments (Single and Paired End, depending on the experiment). I ran [FASTQC](https://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/) in all the samples and found overrepresented adapter sequences:[image]

I removed the adaptors (TruSeq adaptors) using [Cutadapt](http://cutadapt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide.html) (in addition, I removed low quality and N bases from the 3' end of the reads). After that, I ran again FASTQC and the output is the following (representative example) :
[image]

Does anyone know what is happening? Now I have an overrepresented sequence for which no sequence is provided. What does this mean?

Comment: Looks like you trimmed your sequences to nothing.  Do you have empty fastq entries in the file?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment, this was the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @AaronBerlin mentioned, you didn't remove reads that were completely trimmed. Next time use the `--minimum-length` option and set it to something reasonable, like 20. Alternatively, use "Trim Galore!", which is a wrapper around cutadapt that has more reasonable defaults.

Comment: Indeed this was the problem, I set the --minimum-length parameter to 20 and everything is fine. I didn't try Trim Galore! because I am working in a cluster and it is not installed at this moment but in the future I will try it as it seems more intuitive.